# Serilog WriteTo.MSSqlServer Not working Console (Not Core)

Tags: serilog

I'm having issues with WriteTo.MSSqlServer not wring to the configured database. AutitTo.MSSqlServer work fine.  This is in a console app, C#.  Not Core.

I've looked all over and everything I've found is a dead end.  Getting a little frustrated

Code:

```
var sinkOptions = new SinkOptions() { 
        TableName = "Logs",
        AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
        SchemaName = "dbo"
        };
       

        //Create/Configure the logger
        _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File(@"C:\Users\c.clover\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Log.txt")
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            "Server=TEST01;Database=LogDb;Trusted_Connection=True;",
            sinkOptions,
            null,
            null,
            Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information
            )
        .AuditTo.MSSqlServer(
            "Server=TEST01;Database=LogDb;Trusted_Connection=True;",
            sinkOptions,
            null,
            null,
            Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information
            )
        .CreateLogger();
         


        //Log something
        _logger.Information("Test Log {Now}", DateTime.Now);

        Log.CloseAndFlush();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by bagging ILogger _logger  and using Log instead

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()... etc

Log.Information.... etc.

Log.CloseAndFlush();

What I dont get is why it doesnt work with ILogger?

Comment: If you just use the `Logger` itself and not the static `Log` class, you need to dispose the logger to flush it; i.e. `using var logger = new LoggerConfiguration() ....`